# Class disappear from a tr line - Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm a little bit confused with this and I was hoping you could help me.

Here is what I print:

[image: print]

As you can see there is 3 level: The first one is contrat (first tr) 
 
The second one is the bold one (second tr)
The third is the the lines following (third and fourth tr)

My firefox debug is showing this

[image: html]

As you can see, you can find again the 3 level.

The first one is `header_6` 
The second is `firstEnquete content_6`
The third is just `content_6`

But what I don't understand is why my fourth tr has no class.

I'm not showing the full code (I got condition for the differents level, but that's not that important here) but here is the structure :

```
{% set k_enq =0 %}
{% set oldContrat = 0 %}
{% for key, enquete in enquetes %}
    {% if enquete.contract_id != oldContrat %}
        {% set k_enq=k_enq+1 %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set oldContrat= enquete.contract_id %}

    {# first level #}
    <tr id="header_{{ k_enq }}" onclick="toggleContrat(this.id);">
        <td colspan="11" class="contractTR"><span>{{'Contract'|trans|upper}} {{enquete.contract_id}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    {# second level #}
    {% if mission != enquete.mission %}
        {% set mission = enquete.mission %}
            <tr class="{{ enquete.mission }} firstEnquete content_{{ k_enq }}" style="display:none;">
            {% if enquete.is_pack %}
                <td class="pdvTaille2" style="width:40%;">
                    <span style="color:#000000;">{{ enquete.code_mission }} - {{ enquete.nom_mission }}</span>
                </td>
                <td class="periodeTaille2">{{ enquete.nom }}</td>
                <td class="dateTaille periodeautorise">
                    {{ periodeAutorise|raw }}
                </td>
                <td class="dateTaille asaisirdate">
                    {% include('McFrontendBundle:Enquetes:asaisir-date.html.twig') with { enquete : enquete } %}
                </td>
                <td class="actions_"></td>                   
          {% endif %}
          </tr>
  {% endif %}>

  {# third level (i'm not showing the td content it's not usefull) #}
  <tr class="content_{{ k_enq }}" style="display:none;"
      <td class="pdvTaille2"></td>
      <td class="periodeTaille2"></td>
      <td class="dateTaille periodeautorise"></td>
      <td class="dateTaille asaisirdate"></td>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
      <td class="actions darkGreen"></td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't think your code shows the part where you render the fourth tr?

Comment: He does, it's the third level one. You don't see everything but bascily for the iteration 4, it will only enter in that tr, because the first and second are on conditions. 
There is no other tr in the code. All is here.

Comment: Within a single for loop only 3 tr elements get rendered. Only the second tr is conditional. If the fourth tr in the output is also generated by the "third level" code (in a following loop run), why isn't it preceeded by a first level tr (which is **not** conditional!) in the output then? To me it seems that the given output can't be generated by the given twig code, but maybe I'm just missing something obvious here.

Comment: The first one is conditionnal too ! Just as I said in the previous comment "the first and second are on conditions", I din't put the all code because it's not usefull for the understanding, or I can put the condition...but then someone will tell...hey the parameters of your conditions are not defined...then I will add the 50 lines up...and we will forget what's the main issue^^ Sorry if it's not clear.

Comment: Yes, if you don't put all the code it is not possible or at least very hard to identify the problem. What if the problem lies in a part of the code you didn't write here? Just provide the whole loop content unchanged.

Comment: Check the generated html too, not just the parsed dom you're showing in the question.